# The cardinal number of a net of $l_2$ unit ball in $\mathcal{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis

Fo a fixed $\delta\in(0,1)$, denote $\mathcal{N}=\{(x_1,\cdots,x_{n})\in \mathbb{B}_{1}:\text{ }\forall i\text{, } x_i\sqrt{n}/\delta\in \mathbb{Z} \}$, where $\mathbb{B}_{1}$ is the unit ball, i.e. $\mathbb{B}_{1}=\{x=(x_1,\cdots,x_{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{n} :\|x\|_2\leq 1\}$.

Is there any conclusion on the upper bound of the cardinal number, $|\mathcal{N}|$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your set is countable.